# Are covariant derivative on associated bundles exterior covariant derivatives?

Tags: differential-geometry, gauge-theory, differentiation

The gauge covariant derivative we encounter in gauge theory $D\psi = d\psi + A\wedge \psi$ is a covariant derivative on the associated vector bundle, right? Here $\psi$ is the matter field, $A$ the local connection pullback. Is this thing also an exterior covariant derivative？

I am confused partially because Nakahara book section 10.4.1 in page 391 talks about covariant derivative which is on a vector field (hence not a $p$-form?), and the entire book didn't mention exterior covariant derivative. Isn't exterior covariant derivative applied to vector-valued *forms*?

**Edit**: now I am more confused because this [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauge_covariant_derivative) says "gauge covariant derivative is (exactly) the same thing as the exterior covariant derivative on a section of an associated bundle for the principal fiber bundle of the gauge theory."

Comment: There are two different concepts: the covariant derivative acting on sections of associated vector bundles to some principal bundle and the exterior covariant derivative acting on $\mathfrak{g}$-valued forms. I suggest you take a look at chapter 6 of Modern Differential Geometry for Physicists by C. J. Isham. In particular sections 6.2.3 and 6.2.4.

Comment: @Gold I understood and would like to agree but I found this [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauge_covariant_derivative) article which says "gauge covariant derivative is (exactly) the same thing as the exterior covariant derivative on a section of an associated bundle for the principal fiber bundle of the gauge theory"

Comment: That the concepts are different can be appreciated by understanding where each operation is defined. Exterior covariant derivatives act on ${\frak g}$-valued forms,, so we have a map on the space of sections of the bundle of ${\frak g}$-valued forms. The covariant derivative constructed by means of the associated bundle construction acts on sections of such associated bundles, which are not necessarily differential forms. So the operations are defined on different spaces: they can't be the same thing.